# Xamarin scrollview showing white space at end of the grid

Tags: xamarin, scrollview

I have a fixed length grid columns and rows within Scrollview. when I scroll all the way to the end of the grid, the scroll does not stop but stretches a big further, when I release it snaps to end of the grid. Is there a way to avoid this stretching so that scrollview stops exactly at end of the grid?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior in iOS. Any view that has `UIScrollView` will stretch. To avoid it you have to write a CustomRenderer

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    ScrollView.Bounces = false;
}
```